# SwiftUI not updating view based on loader

Tags: swiftui

My view is like this

```
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0 ..< loader.numberOfRows, id: \.self) { index in
                    Image("")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .background(Color.random)
                        .clipped()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My loader is like this

```
final class GiphyLoader {
@Published var data: [GifData] = []
@Published var numberOfRows = 0

init() {
    loadImages()
}

func loadImages() {
    ImageService.getImages { [weak self] response in
        self?.data = response?.data ?? []
        guard let count = response?.data.count else {
            return
        }
        self?.numberOfRows = count
        print(self?.numberOfRows)
    }
}
}
```

The print gives a count of 25 and nothing is displayed on the screen.

But when I change func loadImages to hard code 25 images then it displays 25 like this

```
    func loadImages() {
       numberOfRows = 25
    }
```

How can I dynamically show my views based on what I get from the server?

Comment: `GiphyViewModel` must conform to `ObservableObject` (doesn't the compiler complain?). And how is `GiphyViewModel` created in the view? And `Image("")` seems to be pointless. You have to get some image data from the model.

Comment: Its just used for example to simply it. There is a background color on the image so the images appear even if not loaded from data hence if I hardcode 9 they show up. 

No compiler doesnt complain I'm able to run the app. Why does the view model have to conform to ObservableObject. This is not a requirement of swift.

Comment: My assumption is that you are not using any SwiftUI wrappers. The view won’t know when to update without them. You should look at the SwiftUI tutorials and “Demystify SwiftUI” would help you too, ranges are bad practice.

Comment: What swiftUI wrappers? .

Comment: That is exactly my point, SwiftUI is not like UIKit. Start with the Apple SwiftUI tiutorials.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: I've used the @state wrapper but it's value doesn't change. If I say
self?.numberOfRows = 9
print(self?.numberOfRows)

It just prints 0. Which makes no sense.

Comment: You have to use the right ones. Look at the link above.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a “viewModel” is not a SwiftUI construct, making this slightly nonsensical, and unsolvable.

Comment: @Jessy not a SwiftUI construct? Lol. Tell that to all the Apple documentation and sample code that has view models. There are strong arguments against view models but saying that it isn’t a “SwiftUI construct“ is nonsensical.

Comment: @jessy if this was UIKit this would be working I would to a table reload so this is specifically a swiftUI question.

Comment: I agree it is nonsensical to name this class view model so I took the initiative to rename it to loader (which is what Apple use) to prevent future arguments :-) Now we can argue about why ForEach is not a for loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
   struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var loader = GiphyLoader()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0 ..< loader.numberOfRows, id: \.self) { index in
                    Image("")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .background(Color.random)
                        .clipped()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

If you haven't done so already, be sure to add an extension for `Color` to get a random color. Something like this will do:

```
extension Color {
    static var random: Color {
        return Color(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1)
            )
    }
}
```

And make your loader conform to `ObservableObject` like below.

```
final class GiphyLoader: ObservableObject {
@Published var data: [GifData] = []
@Published var numberOfRows = 0

init() {
    loadImages()
}

func loadImages() {
    ImageService.getImages { [weak self] response in
        self?.data = response?.data ?? []
        guard let count = response?.data.count else {
            return
        }
        self?.numberOfRows = count
        print(self?.numberOfRows)
    }
}
}
```

Then make sure that any subsequent views use the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper instead of `@StateObject`, for example: `@ObservedObject var viewModel: GiphyLoader`.

I can't run it on my end to make sure it works, because I don't have the `ImageService` function or the `GifData` array, but this should solve your problems or at least get you going.

Be sure to understand the different property wrappers and their functions.

[This Hacking with Swift page](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/all-swiftui-property-wrappers-explained-and-compared) should lead you further down the rabbit hole